# IFERROR function in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there any function like `IFERROR` in MySQL. For example:

```
IFERROR(25/0,9)
```

I tried on phpmyadmin but it said that such function `IFERROR` does not exist. Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 3):

YOu can reach similar results with IFNULL:

If an answer is not valid, it defaults to NULL. The IFNULL will then give you the alternative answer:

Your example (in this case):

```
 SELECT IFNULL(25/0,9);
```

Gives as result: 9